# create a new column depend on matching string in columns in two different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have tow data frames A and B,  and I want to match between names columns in tow data frames 
if the name is existing in data set B I need to create a new column in data set A with the Id of data set B if not existing return 0

here is the code I wrote

```
#data B
    email              name        id
    hi@amal.com       amal call     6
    hi@hotmail.com      amal        6
    hi@gmail.com        AMAL boy    6
    hi@boy.com          boy         7
    hi@hotmail.com      boy         7
    hi@call.com     call AMAL       9
    hi@hotmail.com      boy         7
    hi@dog.com          dog         8
    hi@outlook.com      dog         8
    hi@gmail.com        dog         8



#data A

    id  name
    1   amal
    1   AMAL
    2   call
    4   dog
    3   boy
```

first I create contains function

`A.name.str.contains('|'.join(B.name))`

then I tried to create a column

`A["new"] = np.where(A.name.str.contains('|'.join(B.name))==True, B.id, 0)`

but I get this error

`ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,) (10,) ()`

what I expected is

```
    id  name  new
    1   amal  6
    1   AMAL  0
    2   call  0
    4   dog   7
    3   boy   8
```

any help?

Comment: Try to merge dataframes and then `fillna` method.

Comment: `pd.merge(A,B, on='name', how='left')` did a job, but is there any way to pass a list with words in contains function if i want to match words not an exact match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by Series with removed duplicated rows by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), then replace missing values by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) and convert to integers:

```
A["new"] = A.name.map(B.drop_duplicates('name').set_index('name')['id']).fillna(0).astype(int)
print (A)
   id  name  new
0   1  amal    6
1   1  AMAL    0
2   2  call    0
3   4   dog    8
4   3   boy    7
```